# Linux Script to read from file and remove EOF last blank line

Tags: linux

I want to make a script to read this file :
active_users that contains username:email@email.com and then search the disk usage for every user and if disk usage is bigger than limit 1)send email to user 2)save username and these files to a file ->users_over_quota.My problem is that even if I have only one user in active_users my output file ->files_over_quota duplicates records.I think that it takes the eof line which is blank.How can I stop it?.Here's what I have done by far:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename='active_users'
while read -r line; do
        name=$(echo $line | awk -F ":" '{print $1}')
        email=$(echo $line | awk -F ":" '{print $2}')
    mailto=$email
    subject="/home/$name disk usage"
    echo "USERNAME:$name" >>files_over_quota
        find /home/$name -type f -size +500M -exec basename {} \;  >> files_over_quota

    #grep -v '^$' active_users >>files_over_quota
    #mail -s "$subject" $email < /dev/null
    echo "Username and files over limit were saved !"
done <$filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate version of the code you've provided. It will skip blank lines in `$filename`.

```
#!/bin/bash
filename='active_users'
while IFS=":" read -r name email ; do
   case ${name:-emptyLine} in
       emptyLine ) continue ;;
   esac
   mailto="$email"
   subject="/home/$name disk usage"
   echo "USERNAME:$name" > "$name".files_over_quota
   find /home/"$name" -type f -size +500M -exec basename {} \;  >> files_over_quota

    #grep -v '^$' active_users >>  "$name".files_over_quota
    mail -s "$subject" $email < "$name".files_over_quota

    echo "Username and files over limit were saved !"
done <"$filename"
```

It also keeps individual files for each user, so when you send an email its not output for all users.

Also note I have "zeroed-out" the overQuota file at the top of the processing with

```
 echo "USERNAME:$name" > $name.files_over_quota
```

Otherwise, the overQuota file will always be getting bigger.

In the loop processing,

Note that it is much easier in this case to populate `$name` and `$email` by using the `IFS=:"` to tell `read` to split the input-line into fields based on `:`.

And that you can trap an empty line with the short `case` statement. The shell will convert `${name:-`emptyLine}`to just the string`emptyLine`if there is no value found in`$name`.

I don't see you using `mailto`, so maybe you can delete that.

I've enclosed most vars in the code with dbl-quotes because http://shellcheck.net reminded me about that. :-)
I don't have an easy way to test this, so let me know if you get errors.

IHTH

Comment: I run this script but now it doesn't output a user's files that are "over quota" but only username! This should output user's name and  the file(s) name(s) !

Comment: Sorry, but I"m signing off for the day. I hope I haven't made your code worse. If I have, review my comments, and apply what you understand and agree with to **your** copy of  your code. Also `set -vx` may help you see where invalid values for variables are creeping in. If you main problem is the blank line, use your code, but add `case ${line:-emptyLine} in emptyLine ) continue ;; esac` at the top of **your** while loop. Good luck.